# Help Showing a function is identically zero derivative

Tags: complex-analysis

Need help showing that if $f$ is analytic and not identically zero on $A$ then if $f(z_0)=0$, there is an integer $k$ such that $f(z_0) = 0 = \dots = f^{(k-1)}(z_0)$ and $f^{(k)}(z_0) \neq 0$. Any hints on how to get it started? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Look at the power series expansion of $f$ around $z = z_0$ (which converges to $f$ at least on a small disc).

Comment: So: the problem is equivalent to showing that an analytic function is equal to the sum of its Taylor series on a small disk.  To do this, you need the definition of "analytic function" at least.

Comment: Yes, which in my world is the definition of 'analytic'. I prefer 'holomorphic' for functions being complex differentiable on an open set. Preferences may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise, $f^{(k)}(z_0)=0$ for all $k$, hence the Taylor series around $z_0$ is $0$.